# Change font style to Richtextbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to change font style and add it to Richtextbox, this is my code but i get some errors. please help

```
Dim sb = New StringBuilder()

sb.AppendFormat(New Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 12,FontStyle.Regular).AppendLine("SCAN BARCODE: " & txtBarcode.Text)

RichTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text = sb.ToString()
```

Comment: Why do you use a StringBuilder to change the Font? AppendFormat is not intended to format your text with the new font. Font has its own property. Is this WinForms, WPF or ASP.NET?

Comment: yes this is a WinForms, I just added some text to richtextbox, but i need one among them to look like bar-code. thanks

Comment: You need to use the `SelectionFont` property of the `RichTextBox` in much the same way as you would use `SelectionColor` or `SelectionBackColor`.

Comment: I used SelectionFont but it changes an entire Richtextbox controls

Answer (score 0):

To change the font for only a part of the text in your RichTextBox you need to search for the text required, then calculate its length and select it. At this point you can apply the font you want to the SelectionFont property.

```
Sub SetBarCodeText(searchText as String)
    Dim len As Integer = searchText.Length
    Dim pos As Integer = RichTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Find(searchText, 0, RichTextBoxFinds.NoHighlight)
    if pos >= 0 Then
        Dim start As Integer = pos
        Dim endpos As Integer = start + len
        RichTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Select(start, endpos - start)
        RichTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionFont = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 12, FontStyle.Regular)
    End If
End Sub
```

and you call the method above with

```
RichTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text = "SCAN BARCODE: " & txtBarcode.Text
SetBarCodeText("SCAN BARCODE: " & txtBarcode.Text)
```

Comment: I'm Sorry will you share this in vb, my project is in vb and I'm not good in C#. thanks

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you set the caret at the end of the text and set the `SelectionFont`, any text that gets appended will be in that font.

Comment: This worked, but it does not allow me to append some other text. I used StringBuilder to append lines, what i need is to change font style one among the appended line on my StringBuilder.

Comment: Finish to append your text then search for the text that you need in a different font.

Comment: This is what i did but also it does not work, its just appendlines no SCAN BARCODE

```Dim sb = New StringBuilder()```              
```sb.AppendLine("**START OF RECEIPT**")```
```sb.AppendLine(txtshop.Text) ```             
```sb.AppendLine("TIN: " & tin.Text)```               
```RichTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text = sb.ToString()```
```RichTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text = "SCAN BARCODE: " & txtBarcode.Text```
```SetBarCodeText(txtBarcode.Text)```

Comment: I see, append the "SCAN BARCODE...." to your StringBuilder. Now you are replacing the text set by the StringBuilder.ToString with just the SCAN BARCODE:....

Comment: please show me how to append "SCAN BARCODE" I tried but it gives some error

Comment: _sb.AppendLine("SCAN BARCODE: "  & txtBarcode.Text)_

Comment: It does not change font style

Comment: Just for test, instead of using that font, try to change the text to a common font, like Tahoma or Verdana with an higher dotpitch as 18. This is to test if the problem is in the font you choose to use or in the code that I have provided

Comment: I tried but it does not change, is it possible to generate a barcode as an image and the append to richtextbox?

Comment: Why must pos be greater than zero? What if the text searched for is the first text in the RTB?

Comment: Right, it could be zero

Comment: The compiler complains that `end` is not a valid identifier.

Comment: Changed the variable name